# In NiFi, is there a way to scan only the most recently updated part of a log file?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm processing a single log file in NiFi, to search for records containg a particular string, and transfer the filtered records to another file.
(I'm using GetFile->SplitText->RouteText->MergeContent->PutFile)

```
(eg.
=======LOG FILE=======
A=1 | B=2 | C=6 | D=4
A=3 | B=3 | C=7 | D=7
A=5 | B=2 | C=4 | D=7
A=4 | B=2 | C=8 | D=5
A=2 | B=1 | C=9 | D=1

and I'm applying a regex filter of .*B=2.*
)
```

The issue is, the log file is constantly getting new records appended to it, and NiFi scans the ENTIRE file for each iteration.
Is there a way to make NiFi scan only the newly appended records within the file?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of GetFile processor use [TailFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TailFile/) processor.

- TailFile processor pulls only the newly appended lines to the LogFile.

***Processor Configs:***

`Tailing Mode` property as `SingleFile`, [This](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TailFile/additionalDetails.html) link explains in detailed how to configure TailFile processor for SingleFile mode

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/141502/how-tailfile-works-with-multiple-files.html) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/194537/tailfile-multiple-directory-same-file-not-working.html) links for usage/configuration of TailFile processor.

Comment: Thank you! Also one more thing, does this work only for local files? Or can I apply this to remote log files as well? (NiFi running on a local machine, log file on remote system)

Comment: If you are using GetFile processor now then you can replace with TailFile processor apart of that **I don't think we can access remote files using TailFile processor**, Refer to this link regards to the same exact use case https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/10388/nifi-tailfile-on-remote-hosts.html